# How to create an arrayList using Costum objects on C#

Tags: c#

I want to add objects on a dynamic list for use it after on other cases, I'm new on C# .net and I tried this piece of code:

```
class DashboardClass
    {
        private int prix;
        private string name;
        private int quantity;

        public void SetInfo(string name, int prix, int quantity)
        {
            this.prix = prix;
            this.quantity = quantity;
            this.name = name;
        }

        public int getprix()
        {
            return prix;
        }
        public string getname()
        {
            return name;
        }

        public int getquantity()
        {
            return quantity;
        }
    }
```

and on my main form :

```
 DashboardClass Object = new DashboardClass();
         List<object> ProductList = new List<object>();
        DashboardClass item = Object.SetInfo("ala", 152, 1);
        ProductList.Add(item);
```

please how to modify my code for making a list of Productlist.

Comment: Are you sure you want a list of `object`s, not a list of `DashboardClass`es?

Comment: I want an object that I can access to it by object.name for exemple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your setinfo to constructor.

```
class DashboardClass
    {
        private int prix;
        private string name;
        private int quantity;

        public DashboardClass(string name, int prix, int quantity)
        {
            this.prix = prix;
            this.quantity = quantity;
            this.name = name;
        }

        public int getprix()
        {
            return prix;
        }
        public string getname()
        {
            return name;
        }

        public int getquantity()
        {
            return quantity;
        }
    }
```

This way you can use object to access prix,name and quantity through get methods.

```
List<DashboardClass> cls = new List<DashboardClass>();
            cls.Add(new DashboardClass("example", 1, 1));
            Console.WriteLine(cls[0].getprix());
            Console.Read();
```

cls[0] here is accessing the first object in the generic list.

When you have more objects in the list just iterate using foreach loop

Answer (score 0):

are you looking for something like this?

```
class DashboardClass
{
    private int prix;
    private string name;
    private int quantity;

    public void DashboardClass(string name, int prix, int quantity)
    {
        this.prix = prix;
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getprix()
    {
        return prix;
    }
    public string getname()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public int getquantity()
    {
        return quantity;
    }
}
```

then

```
List<object> ProductList = new List<object>();
DashboardClass item = new DashboardClass("ala", 152, 1);
ProductList.Add(item);
```

or Typed way **(Added according to authors comment)**

```
List<DashboardClass> ProductList = new List<DashboardClass>();
DashboardClass item = new DashboardClass("ala", 152, 1);
ProductList.Add(item);
```